# error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class. Is it missing an @NgModule annotation?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I am getting this error in my super simple Angular app and I do not know why I am getting this error.   I a providing a screenshot that should answer most questions you might have.

```
error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be 
  resolved to an NgModule class.
    Is it missing an @NgModule annotation?
```

[image]

NOTE: When I first generated the ChannelService class, it was compiling, but stopped working after I fiddled around with it.   I tried the obvious things like deleting `node_modules` and rebuilding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a service in your module imports, it is a provider and should be automatically registered because it is `providedIn: 'root'`

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    ChannelService, // <-- remove this
    BrowserModule,
    AgGridModule.withComponents([])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Comment: Thanks,  yep, that was it.  Can't believe I did that.    I went 3 months without creating an Angular app and forgot.   Too much to remember.

Comment: i only knew because i did the same thing myself 